# Change column value based on another column, but only for certain conditions in the first AND second column (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, grepl

I have a dataframe.

```
city <- as.character(c("London", "Unknown", "Birmingham", "Bristol", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"))
city_details <- as.character(c("London", "Camden", "Birmingham", "Outside London", "Camden Town", "Westminster", "London", "Birmingham"))
city_data <- data.frame(city, city_details)
```

Although several of the values in the city column are unknown, looking at the city_details reveals that most of these are actually in London.

So, I can replace some of these:

```
city_data$city[grepl("Camden|Westminster", city_data$city_details)] <- 'London'
```

However, this is more difficult with the one that says "London" in the city_details, because there is also one that says "Outside London", so I don't want to just pick up anything that has the "London" pattern in it.

For the purposes of this, I'm not looking for a way to only include exact matches (because that won't be quite right for my real data).

So what I want to do is only perform this replacement on city values that are unknown.

At the moment I have tried the following, but clearly the logic is off because what it is actually doing is just changing all the unknown values in the city column to London.

```
city_data <- within(city_data, city[city == "Unknown"] <- (city[grepl("London", city_details)] <- 'London'))
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also worked out the following way of doing it, which seems a bit neater and more intuitive to me. No need to convert to numeric.

```
city_data$city[grepl("Unknown", city_data$city) & 
               grepl("London|Camden|Westminster", city_data$city_details)] <- "London"
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you only want to replace the city names when `city` is unknown and `city_details` mentions "London". In this case you can use the following:

`city_data$city[(as.numeric(grepl("Unknown", city)) + as.numeric(grepl("London", city_details))) == 2] <- "London"`

Does this answer your question?

Comment: This does seem to work - thanks! I also included the other city_details in the same line: `city_data$city[(as.numeric(grepl("Unknown", city)) + as.numeric(grepl("London|Camden|Westminster", city_details))) == 2] <- "London"`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
one_hot <- grepl("Camden|Westminster|London", city_data$city_details) &
  city_data$city == "Unknown"
city_data$city[one_hot] <- "London"
```

Example:

```
city <- as.character(c("London", "Unknown", "Birmingham", "Bristol", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown"))
city_details <- as.character(c("London", "Camden", "Birmingham", "Outside London", "Camden Town", "Westminster", "London", "Tottenham"))
city_data <- data.frame(city, city_details)

> city_data
        city   city_details
1     London         London
2    Unknown         Camden
3 Birmingham     Birmingham
4    Bristol Outside London
5    Unknown    Camden Town
6    Unknown    Westminster
7    Unknown         London
8    Unknown      Tottenham

> one_hot <- grepl("Camden|Westminster|London", city_data$city_details) &
+   city_data$city == "Unknown"
> city_data$city[one_hot] <- "London"
> city_data
        city   city_details
1     London         London
2     London         Camden
3 Birmingham     Birmingham
4    Bristol Outside London
5     London    Camden Town
6     London    Westminster
7     London         London
8    Unknown      Tottenham
```

Comment: Thanks. For me this is giving me the same outcome as what I tried previously, which is that all unknowns are changed to London, rather than those that include any of the string patterns mentioned.

Comment: I think that's just your example since all `city` entries with value `Unknown` have a `city_detail` matching the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, I did tweak my code when testing it to include an unknown city that isn't London but hadn't updated the question - I'll edit now to make it clearer. But with an unknown that isn't London, this still makes it London when I run it.

Comment: Oh, true. I've made a mistake in my answer. With the new edit, my solution should also work.